# "426 Failure writing network stream." received when trying connect to an FTP site with Java's URL Class

Tags: java, url, ftp

I have some Java code which looks roughly like this:

```
String urlString = "ftp://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/history/waves/multi_1.glo_30m.dp.200601.grb2";
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

When I get to the last line, the code hangs and never returns. When I attach Wireshark and look at the conversation, it ends like this:

```
...
EPSV ALL
200 EPSV ALL ok.
EPSV
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||32647|)
EPRT |1|144.212.217.249|58416|
200 EPRT command successful. Consider using EPSV.
RETR multi_1.glo_30m.dp.200601.grb2
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for multi_1.glo_30m.dp.200601.grb2 (55796622 bytes).
426 Failure writing network stream.
```

This URL works fine in my browser. Other sites work fine with this Java code. Any ideas why this combination is having trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a bug in Sun's implementation. I've reported it here:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7148208